# Failed to resolve module specifier "svelte". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am having problems running my svelte project that I have on my machine.

I run the command: "yarn dev" and then it opens the project in the browser, but in the google console the following message appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "svelte". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

The problem is that it doesn't say specifically where this error is.
Has anyone had a similar problem? I have no idea where the error is. If you need me to put more information, just ask, I really don't know what could be happening.